# asking speculatory questions

Tags: discussion

Is asking a question like "would Diego Maradona have scored his legendary goal if he was playing today?" considered off topic?

Answering this would require a lot of speculation, clearly, so I am not sure if it is considered off topic. Many questions in sports that aren't purely about statistics can be speculatory in nature.